Can SPMT migration tool be used to migrate from SharePoint 2019 to SharePoint server-subscription edition
I have only seen examples of SPMT used to migrate SP on-Prem to online, but I was wondering if it is possible to do a migration from SP 2019 to SP subscription edition. Is there another migration tool that I can use (preferably free)

No, SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) can only migrate on-premise SharePoint to SharePoint Online. On-premise to on-premise or online to online is not possible.

The SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT) is a free and easy to use migration solution to help you migrate content from on-premises SharePoint sites to Microsoft 365.

Source: Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)
There is no alternative free tool.
ShareGate, AvePoint DocAve or Quest Content Matrix can achieve this but they are commercial tools.
